# MSOLAP Connection String : Is is possible to access Cube as a particular user

Tags: security, ssas

When Browsing an MS OLAP cube in SQL Server Management Studio I'm able to click on the change user button to change the user that I view the cube as. This let me test security access to various parts of the data.

[image]

I was wondering if it's possible to do this in the connection string also? As far as I understand it I can change the **Roles** property in the connection string, but as the data is locked from particular person's perspective this doesn't help. Also the cube uses windows security so a specific user and password combo aren't going to help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, through the following property in your connection string:

```
EffectiveUserName=DOMAIN\UserName
```

**This will only work if you're an SSAS administrator**.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question then, but you might be looking for the `EffectiveUserName` property.

Comment: Thank you `EffectiveUserName` is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

in your ConnectionString you can use `CustomData="Username"` and After that you can used it like `UserName()` Function.
PLEASE See this link for more information about CustomData()
http://www.mdxpert.com/Functions/MDXFunction.aspx?f=154